# How to delete AWS Service catalog portfolio in AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-service-catalog

I'm trying to delete Service catalog portfolio on my account, but I'm getting following error:

> **Delete portfolio failed**
>
> Portfolio port-xxx still has associated Principals

Comment: Did you delete the Prinicipals?

Comment: thank you @stdunbar, I delete the resources. now I can delete the Service catalog Portfolio.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all principles, shares, constraints and products and then you will be able to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

We have faced the same issue and we have to remove the IAM roles that are associated with the portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

1. First click on the Portfolio that you want to delete.
2. Goto the tab, Users and roles.
3. Select the associated user and delete it from the Portfolio one by one.
4. Now try to delete the Portfolio.